# ASYNCIO Issues. "Future pending"

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, joblib

I am currently having issues with Joblib running multiprocessing, or a parallel program. I was able to get this to work before, and I was reaching times of 1 min total, however, I went about and changed up a lot, and messed something up. I have posted the barebones code, as I am receiving the same error with it. I am trying to loop through all 150 stock symbols, and use yahoo finance to receive the option chain for each one. I am trying to do this on a minute basis. I have also tried other libraries like asyncio, and have been unsuccessful with that. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

```
import yfinance as yf


def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

done = []
@background
def downloadChain(ticker):
    print(ticker)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    daysOut = 100
    chain = 0
    try:
        yf_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        expiration_dates = yf_ticker.options
        for expiration_date in expiration_dates:
            if (datetime.fromisoformat(expiration_date) - datetime.now()).days <= daysOut:
                try:
                    chain = yf_ticker.option_chain(expiration_date)
                    df = df.append(chain)

                except Exception as e:
                    pass
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    done.append(ticker)
```

Main function:

```
symbols = ["WATT","TSLA","UVXY","VXX","KEYS","EGO","GLD","WORK","BYND","BLK","PINS","LYFT","SPCE","PAYC","WDAY","UBER","CHGG","SHAK","CMG","CTL","ACB","TLRY","CGC","MJ","ORCL","GRUB","RNG","JWN","TTWO","ADI","ATVI","EA","SNE","GAMR","TXN","TMUS","MCHP","TSM","XBI","ETFC","MS","IWM","EXPD","RCL","CCL","MOMO","BABA","VMW","CRM","ULTA","SKYY","SPLK","FLWS","AVGO","TWTR","PANW","RJF","SABR","LOW","RS","ON","VEEV","DOCU","FB","SNAP","HPQ","RACE","F","AMAT","MRO","STM","AAL","DAL","VICR","XLC","CRON","DELL","T","VZ","S","MELI","CVM","REGN","NVAX","APT","CODX","LAKE","MRNA","EBS","INO", "SPY","SH","QQQ","XLF","KRE","XLV","HYG","LQD","NET","NFLX","ROKU","SHOP","AMZN","AAPL","MSFT","GOOGL","GOOG","NVDA","MU","AMD","INTC","MRVL","QCOMM","SQ","PYPL","TTD","TSLA","ZM","TDOC","LVGO","MDB","HD","VNQ","ARI","ACC","IIPR","EQR","EPR","SPG","PLD","ACB","WHR","NVAX","APT","MDT","CLRX","COST","SDC","LK","PVH","KSS","M","LULU","NKE","KO","BAC","JPM","CS","WFC","ARKW","ARKK","MGM","AMAT","WYNN","TGT","ITT","FXI"]   


for ticker in symbols:
    downloadChain(ticker)
```

I added a separate loop to see the size of the "done" array, which holds all the symbols that have been completed. I am unsure what i have changed, but now this loop is completing in about 10-15 mins when 1 minute is expected.

```
while True:
    clear_output(wait=True)
    print(len(done))
```

Comment: Can you, please, separate the "main" and downloadChain function? What error are you getting? Which package is `yf`? [yahoo-finance](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/) that I found was last updated 4 years ago.

Comment: I have done these things, thanks. I am not receiving any errors, just a very long run time, similar to the run time of non-parallelizing.  yf is yfinance, which is maintained, and not the root of the issue I believe.

Comment: Cheers. Have you tried using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` executor? Specifically, explicitly telling `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor` to use an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Comment: I have not. Where should I add this line, as i am new to asyncio, and threading as a whole? I am just trying to get through this part so I can update this database as fast as possible.

Comment: Import it from `concurrent.futures`. Turn `return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)` into `return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor, f, *args, **kwargs)`. Then, wrap your `for ticker in symbols` block with a `with` clause, similar  to the examples in the doc. `with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:`.

Comment: Thanks @edd , I have done what you said, however, i am not sure how executor gets passed to the background function. I am getting  "NameError: name 'executor' is not defined" error at the new line you had told me to update, return...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of the "fix". Adding them as an answer rather than using comments as a chat :)

```py
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

done = []
@background
def downloadChain(ticker):
    print(ticker)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    daysOut = 100
    chain = 0
    try:
        yf_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        expiration_dates = yf_ticker.options
        for expiration_date in expiration_dates:
            if (datetime.fromisoformat(expiration_date) - datetime.now()).days <= daysOut:
                try:
                    chain = yf_ticker.option_chain(expiration_date)
                    df = df.append(chain)

                except Exception as e:
                    pass
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    done.append(ticker)


symbols = ["WATT","TSLA","UVXY","VXX","KEYS","EGO","GLD","WORK","BYND","BLK","PINS","LYFT","SPCE","PAYC","WDAY","UBER","CHGG","SHAK","CMG","CTL","ACB","TLRY","CGC","MJ","ORCL","GRUB","RNG","JWN","TTWO","ADI","ATVI","EA","SNE","GAMR","TXN","TMUS","MCHP","TSM","XBI","ETFC","MS","IWM","EXPD","RCL","CCL","MOMO","BABA","VMW","CRM","ULTA","SKYY","SPLK","FLWS","AVGO","TWTR","PANW","RJF","SABR","LOW","RS","ON","VEEV","DOCU","FB","SNAP","HPQ","RACE","F","AMAT","MRO","STM","AAL","DAL","VICR","XLC","CRON","DELL","T","VZ","S","MELI","CVM","REGN","NVAX","APT","CODX","LAKE","MRNA","EBS","INO", "SPY","SH","QQQ","XLF","KRE","XLV","HYG","LQD","NET","NFLX","ROKU","SHOP","AMZN","AAPL","MSFT","GOOGL","GOOG","NVDA","MU","AMD","INTC","MRVL","QCOMM","SQ","PYPL","TTD","TSLA","ZM","TDOC","LVGO","MDB","HD","VNQ","ARI","ACC","IIPR","EQR","EPR","SPG","PLD","ACB","WHR","NVAX","APT","MDT","CLRX","COST","SDC","LK","PVH","KSS","M","LULU","NKE","KO","BAC","JPM","CS","WFC","ARKW","ARKK","MGM","AMAT","WYNN","TGT","ITT","FXI"]   

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for ticker in symbols:
        downloadChain(ticker)
```

The second being more standard. In which we define an `async` main which we ask `asyncio` to use as the main entry point.

```py
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


symbols = ["WATT","TSLA","UVXY","VXX","KEYS","EGO","GLD","WORK","BYND","BLK","PINS","LYFT","SPCE","PAYC","WDAY","UBER","CHGG","SHAK","CMG","CTL","ACB","TLRY","CGC","MJ","ORCL","GRUB","RNG","JWN","TTWO","ADI","ATVI","EA","SNE","GAMR","TXN","TMUS","MCHP","TSM","XBI","ETFC","MS","IWM","EXPD","RCL","CCL","MOMO","BABA","VMW","CRM","ULTA","SKYY","SPLK","FLWS","AVGO","TWTR","PANW","RJF","SABR","LOW","RS","ON","VEEV","DOCU","FB","SNAP","HPQ","RACE","F","AMAT","MRO","STM","AAL","DAL","VICR","XLC","CRON","DELL","T","VZ","S","MELI","CVM","REGN","NVAX","APT","CODX","LAKE","MRNA","EBS","INO", "SPY","SH","QQQ","XLF","KRE","XLV","HYG","LQD","NET","NFLX","ROKU","SHOP","AMZN","AAPL","MSFT","GOOGL","GOOG","NVDA","MU","AMD","INTC","MRVL","QCOMM","SQ","PYPL","TTD","TSLA","ZM","TDOC","LVGO","MDB","HD","VNQ","ARI","ACC","IIPR","EQR","EPR","SPG","PLD","ACB","WHR","NVAX","APT","MDT","CLRX","COST","SDC","LK","PVH","KSS","M","LULU","NKE","KO","BAC","JPM","CS","WFC","ARKW","ARKK","MGM","AMAT","WYNN","TGT","ITT","FXI"]   
done = []


def downloadChain(ticker):
    print(ticker)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    daysOut = 100
    chain = 0
    try:
        yf_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
        expiration_dates = yf_ticker.options
        for expiration_date in expiration_dates:
            if (datetime.fromisoformat(expiration_date) - datetime.now()).days <= daysOut:
                try:
                    chain = yf_ticker.option_chain(expiration_date)
                    df = df.append(chain)

                except Exception as e:
                    pass
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    done.append(ticker)


async def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for ticker in symbols:
            asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(executor, downloadChain,
                                                     ticker)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Here you also have more refined control over which executor to use. Basically, we explicitly code under which event loop we're working with and under which we add work to an executor. Local tests didn't show great differences between `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`.